# how i get friends check in on facebook place

Tags: facebook

i have question about get friends visited on facebook page

[sample page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Phuket-Thailand/138208192871081?nr=113336155343640)

i see my friend visited on this page. how can i get friends on this?

i find on Graph API Explorer and topic on stackoverflow

but i try this

```
fql?q=SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = 138208192871081 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

it's not show data.

now i don't have way to try this.

help me please.

thank.